# Using tableau command line refresh extract with multiple connection

Tags: tableau-api

I have published an extract over Tableau Server which I need to update into every 10 minutes.I am able to do so when a single connection is involved using tableau command line.

```
tableau refreshextract --server https://online.tableau.com --username user1 --password pass  --project project --datasource data_123 --source-username connection1 --source-password connection1
```

How I can refresh the extract if extract was generated from two or more connections.
I have tried above commands but it's not working.

Error `There is no active connection to the data source`

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up a schedule on the server. Sign in to the server, go to the Schedules page, and click New Schedule. Set the recurrence to be every 10 minutes.
2. Enable scheduled extract refreshes and failure emails. As a server or site administrator, you can enable schedules, as well as email notification when extract refreshes fail.

   Select Settings, and then go to the General page.

   Under Email Notification, select Send email to data source and workbook owners when scheduled refreshes fail.

   Under Embedded Credentials, select both check boxes to allow publishers to embed credentials and schedule extract refreshes.
3. Publish a workbook with an extract. In Tableau Desktop, select Server > Publish Workbook. Sign in to the server if you’re not already. In the Publish Workbook to Tableau Server dialog box , click Schedules & Authentication. Under Extract Schedule, select the schedule from the list.

See the Tableau Quick Start at https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/qs_refresh_extracts.html

Comment: can't we do this using command line utility?It's working with a single connection.

Comment: @Gulshan no, you cannot do it. Quoting from the command line utility help docs, "You can use it to refresh single-connection data sources only. It does not work for multi-connection data sources." See http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/to_refresh_extract_commandline.htm

Comment: using `tabcmd refreshextracts` i am able to refresh multi-connection data source, its just with `tableau *****` command line its not possible.